# After saving email with an attachment into a depository, open it again, the attachment seems to have extra duplicate extension

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, mapi

We have an Outlook add-in that uses MAPI. But after we save an email with attachment such as excel file, "Sample.xlsx" into our depository, then reopen it from the depository, it shows the email with an attachment "Sample.xlsx.xlsx"
In brief we use these:

```
CComPtr<IMessage> pMsgNew;
hRes = pMsg->CopyTo(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, (LPIID)&IID_IMessage, pMsgNew, 0, NULL);

hRes = pMsgNew->SaveChanges (KEEP_OPEN_READWRITE);
hRes = pStorage->Commit(STGC_DEFAULT);
```

Is it the way Outlook works?

Comment: No, it certainly does not. Do you manipulate the attachments in any way? Or just take IMessage from Outlook and copy everything to an MSG file using CopyTo?

Comment: No. I just copy straight without touching the attachment. I don't see how could I attach pictures of them here for you to see the attachment before and after.

Comment: Do you get the same results when you do the same things using the Outlook Object Model?

Comment: Hi Eugene, No. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: But I think that the way Outlook display the attachment after "Copy". I could see the same thing when I right click on an email from my Inbox, select Copy, then Paste it to the Desktop, then open it from the Desktop, I could see the different "display" of the attachment as well.

Comment: What do you see n OutlookSpy (click IMessage to see a message in Outlook or OpenIMsgOnIStg to open an MSG file) if you go to the GetAttachmentTable tab?